# JSP Button not responding

Tags: jsp

Whenever I click on the "Create Account" Button on my jsp page, nothing's happening. Following is the code for the form :

```
 <form method="post" action="" name="accountForm" id="accountForm">
                    <label for="accountName">Account Name:</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="accountName" id="accountName" /> <br /> 
                    <label for="accountContact">Account Contact:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="accountContact" id="accountContact" /> <br />
                    <label for="projectId">Project Id:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="projectId" id="projectId" /> <br />
                    <label for="projectName">Project Name:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="projectName" id="projectName" /> <br />
                    <label for="ilcCode">Account Id:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="ilcCode" id="ilcCode" /> <br />
                    <label for="licenseNo">License Key:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="licenseNo" id="licenseNo" /> <br />
                    <label for="iot">IOT:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                    <select name="iot">
                    <%  while(resultset2.next()){ %>
        <option><%= resultset2.getString(1)%></option>
    <% } %>
                    </select> <br />
                    <label for="active">active:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="active">

                    <br /> <input type="button" value="Create Account" onclick="updateAccount();">
                    <input type="button" value="Search Account" onclick="searchAccount();">
                </form>
```

Following is the code for the updateAccount() method :

```
       function updateAccount()
 {
var accName = document.getElementById("accountName").value;
var accContact = document.getElementById("accountContact").value;
var projId = document.getElementById("projectId").value;
var projName = document.getElementById("projectName").value;
var ilCd = document.getElementById("ilcCode").value;
var licsnNo = document.getElementById("licenseNo").value;
var iot = document.getElementById("iot").value;
var active = document.getElementById("active").value;
 $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "AccountController",  
        data: {"action":"createAccount",
            "accountName":accName,"accountContact":accContact,"projectId":projId,"projectName":projName,"ilcCode":ilCd,"licenseNo":licsnNo,"iot":iot,"active":active},  
        success: function(data,jqXHR){  
            $("#accMessageDiv").html(data);
        }, 
        error: function(data,jqXHR){  
            $("#accMessageDiv").html(data);
        }, 
        beforeSend: function() {
                // setting a timeout

        },
        complete: function()
        {

        }
      }); 

 }
```

Following is the createAccount method in my AccountController class :

```
 protected void createAccount(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    String error;

    Account account = new Account();

    account = fillAttributes(account, request);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    AccountDAO accountDAO = new AccountDAOImpl();

    int result=0;
    try {
        if(account.getAccName() != null && account.getProjectId() != null)
            result = accountDAO.createAccount(account);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     if (account.getAccName() == null && account.getProjectId() == null ) {
        error = "Enter Valid Account Details.";

        out.write(error);
    } else {
        String msg = "Account  :"+account.getAccName() + "  successfully added. ";
        out.write(msg);
        /*session.setAttribute("message", msg);
        session.removeAttribute("error");
        response.sendRedirect("index2.jsp");*/
    }

}
```

Following is the fillAttributes method in the Account class:

```
 private Account fillAttributes(Account account,HttpServletRequest request)
{

    account.setAccName(checkNull(request.getParameter("accountName")));
    account.setAccContact(checkNull(request.getParameter("accountContact")));
    account.setProjectId(checkNull(request.getParameter("projectId")));
    account.setProjectName(checkNull(request.getParameter("projectName")));
    account.setIlcCode(checkNull(request.getParameter("ilcCode")));
    account.setLicenseNo(checkNull(request.getParameter("licenseNo")));
    account.setIot(checkNull(request.getParameter("iot")));
    account.setActive(false);

    return account;
}
private String checkNull(String input)
{
    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(input))
        return input;
    else
        return null;

}
```

Whenever I am running the jsp on the tomcat server, the UI gets generated but when I click on the "CreateAccount" button, absolutely nothing happens. Please help me to get this resolved.

Comment: put a break point in **createAccount** class and see whether the execution comes to break point. If not inspect the JS function using any inspector in browser, you can also check for any errors in the browser inspector while you click the button

Comment: Please check browser console.May be there is javascript error.